# Latin-language newspaper

Tags: teaching-method

I took Latin in high school (c1995, United States) and each student in my class had a subscription to a Latin-language newspaper.  I think it was published once a month or maybe bi-weekly, and it was intended for students taking the language.  Is anyone familiar enough to recognize this and remember the name?  I would like to find out if it is still publishing.

Comment: It's worth noting, Google is not much help as "latin-language newspaper" tends to lead to Latin American resources.  Neat, but not helping here.

Comment: Online there’s. http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net/

Comment: The Times(UK) each Saturday has a Latin Crossword (main paper, last page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the grand tradition of things always being in the last place you left them, despite searching for several days, I found the answer on my own a few hours after I posted this.  The newspaper was called *Pompeiiana* and was published from 1974 to 2003.  Apparently the entire back catalog is available, *legally*, online at http://pompeiiana.blogspot.com/.